# How to isolate algebraic fraction in this case

Tags: fractions

i have a question about of how to isolate an equation, when it has a multiplication in the denominator.

```
a/b/3  is same than a*(3/b)
```

but, when is:

```
a/(b/3 * 4/a)
```

If i want to isolate the `4/a` that is multiplying the `b/3` and in turn dividing to `a`, so how isolate only the `4/a` ?

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\frac{a}{\frac{b}{3}\cdot \frac{4}{a}}=\frac{3a^2}{4b}$$